# Que esta mal en esta funcion? Returns devuelven undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Quiero hacer una funcion que devuelva la data de este proceso pero no estoy lograndolo ya que al ejecutar la misma y enviarle una id esta devuelve undefined

```js
var getData = function(id) {
  db.collection('users').doc(id).get()
  .then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
      return doc.data();
  } else {
    return 'Document not found';
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
  return error;
});
}
```

Comment: podrías agregar donde llamas a la función y que id le pasas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que se esta solicitando un recurso asíncrono se necesita manejar de la misma manera, no es posible que la *promesa* se ejecute de manera sincrona, es por esto que planteo una solución al problema:

> Es probable que se necesiten muchos más cambios en el código para que lo siguiente funcione correctamente, solo pretendo mostrar la forma como se debería realizar el proceso.

```
var getData = function (id) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    db.collection('users').doc(id).get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          resolve(doc.data());
        }

        reject('Document not found');
      })
      .catch(function (exception) {
        reject(exception);
      })
  });
}

var id = 6;

getData(id).then(function (data) {
  console.log('Datos:', data);
  // Proceso a realizar
}).catch(function (exception) {
  console.error('Exeption:', exception);
});
```

[Documentación de las Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ahora tienes idea como seria mejor para pasarle varias id? Yo habia pensado en un for que pase por esa funcion cada id, y luego guarde los datos de todas las id pasadas en otro array

Comment: En ese caso se debe realizar una cola de promesas, en el caso que se tengan que buscar 3 id's se lanzan las 3 promesas y se almacenan en una variable, posterior a esto se evalúa que cada una halla terminado con `Promise.all(iterable)` en el `then` se debe continuar el proceso. en la documentación puede leer un poco más del tema.

Comment: Me podrias pasar algun documento o algo que este mas especificado? Soy medio nuevo con esto de las promises. Muchas gracias por la mano

Comment: En la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all) hay varios ejemplos que espero sea de ayuda.